# why its showing error when try to print last array index in string

Tags: java

why when i try to run this code in java its keep say its arrayindexoutof

```
 String[] animals = new String[0];
System.out.println(animals[0]);
```

where is the wrong in the code above

Comment: The last array index is obviously not the same value as the array size.

Comment: You're creating an array of length zero, and then trying to access the first index.  In the range of `0` to `0`, there is no `1`.  So it's "out of bounds".

Comment: "I need an array which can hold zero animals, now give me the  1st animal on it...."... does this make sense?

Comment: dude try to run this i also will show erroe for u :)

String[] animals = new String[1];
System.out.println(animals[1]);

@David

Comment: @Onecode: Now you're creating an array of length 1 and asking for the *second* index.  Same problem, for the same reason.  Indexes *start at zero*.  So `animals[1]` is asking for the *second* element.  An array that's of length 1 has no second element.

Answer (score 1):

Because you allocated a zero-length array and tried to access its first member. Note that in Java arrays are zero-indexed.

Comment: String[] animals = new String[1];
System.out.println(animals[1]);


i will also show error :)

Comment: Because, again, java arrays are zero-indexed. You just allocated an array of size 1 and tried to access its _second_ element by using index 1.

Comment: but in array its count from zero

Answer (score 0):

Dude...
You're creating an empty array of strings..
This is how you do it

```html
String[] animals = new String[1];
System.out.println(animals[0]);
```

Comment: dude try to run this code  
String[] animals = new String[1];
System.out.println(animals[1]);

Comment: ... well that's also out of bounds. you need to run animals[0] cuz' that's where the arrays start from in Java. 1st member is on index 0

Answer (score 0):

String[] animals = new String[0];
Here 0 defines the size of the array,so cannot access first element as its 0 size array